# Multiple mediaplayers into one

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm making a soundboard application and I've added a lot of `MediaPlayer` instances in my Java file to start whenever I click on a `CardView`. Is there a way I can make them all into one media player?

```
//Muziekje bingo
final MediaPlayer bingoMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bingo);

final CardView bingo = (CardView) this.findViewById(R.id.play_bingo);

bingo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bingoMediaPlayer.start();
        bingo.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#707980"));
    }
});

bingoMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        bingo.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b3bac0")); // finish current activity
    }
});

//muziekje harrypotter
final MediaPlayer harrypotterMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.harrypotter);

final CardView harrypotter = (CardView) this.findViewById(R.id.play_harrypotter);

harrypotter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        harrypotterMediaPlayer.start();
        harrypotter.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#707980"));
    }
});


    harrypotterMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            harrypotter.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b3bac0")); // finish current activity
        }
    });

    //muziekje bibet
    final MediaPlayer bibetMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bibet);

    final CardView bibet = (CardView) this.findViewById(R.id.play_bibet);

    bibet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bibetMediaPlayer.start();
            bibet.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#707980"));
        }
    });



    bibetMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            bibet.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b3bac0")); // finish current activity
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest to go native, if your working on something like mixing music etc. https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to play relevant music file. This will help you to get rid of boilerplate code.

```
public void playSound(int music) {
    //mContext will be your context here
    MediaPlayer.create(mContext, music).start();
}
```

And you can use this function in your code like this

```
bingo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.bingo);
            bingo.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#707980"));
         }
    });

harrypotter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(R.raw.harrypotter);
            harrypotter.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#707980"));
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps you.